# kendo mobile listview click event does not fire

Tags: kendo-mobile

I have place a div element inside the list view template and I have added data tab event for that div element, the problem is if I tab the div the list view click event fired so I have add the following line inside the div element tab event e.event.stopPropagation(), this line prevent the list view click event firing while tab on div element. but after that the list view click event does not firing. how to handle this problem.

Comment: Perhaps edit your original question and provide the actual code so it's a bit more effective to help you.

Comment: Hi this is the sample code http://jsbin.com/qipam/1 if I click the button the listview click event also firing how to prevent this.